# Overflowing a child element outside the parent element

Tags: html, css

I have a simple card which contains an image `.menu-card__header-image`. On hover, I wish to *lift* that image up by some pixels. However, when I do lift the image, the image is not visible outside the parent container `.menu-card`.

```css
.menu-card {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: red;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 80%;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  max-width: 400px;
}
.menu-card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  overflow: visible;
}
.menu-card__header {
  background-color: orange;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% calc(100% - 6vw), 0 100%);
  max-height: 300px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}
.menu-card__header-image {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  z-index: 33;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0px;
  transition: bottom 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.menu-card:hover .menu-card__header-image {
  bottom: 80px;
}
.menu-card:first-child {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.menu-card:last-child {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.menu-card__title {
  padding: 0 12px;
}
.menu-card__description {
  padding: 0 12px;
}

.menu-card__title {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-card">
  <div class="menu-card__header">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/635" alt="" class="menu-card__header-image" height="400px" />
  </div>
  <h2 class="menu-card__title">
    Lorem Ipsum
  </h2>
  <p class="menu-card__description">
    Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corrupti, architecto. Repudiandae dolorum incidunt sint ex
  </p>
</div>
```

Here is the relevant pen:  https://codepen.io/saifalfalah/pen/gJKNBE?editors=1100

How do I make the image be visible outside the parent container on hover without changing the markup (preferably)?

Comment: I posted an answer and I'm messing with your codepen to see if I can get you a working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option without changing the markup is to *animate* the `clip-path` property as well to change to `clip-path: polygon(0 -80px, 100% -80px, 100% calc(100% - 6vw), 0 100%)` on hover - see demo below:

```css
body {
  margin-top: 100px; /* for illustration */
}

.menu-card {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 80%;
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  max-width: 400px;
}
.menu-card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  /*overflow: visible;*/
}
.menu-card:hover .menu-card__header { /* added */
   clip-path: polygon(0 -80px, 100% -80px, 100% calc(100% - 6vw), 0 100%);
}
.menu-card__header {
  background-color: orange;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% calc(100% - 6vw), 0 100%);
  max-height: 300px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
  text-align: center;
  transition: clip-path 0.5s ease-in-out; /* added */
}
.menu-card__header-image {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  z-index: 33;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0px;
  transition: bottom 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.menu-card:hover .menu-card__header-image {
  bottom: 80px;
}
.menu-card__title {
  padding: 0 12px;
}
.menu-card__description {
  padding: 0 12px;
}

.menu-card__title {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-card">
  <div class="menu-card__header">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/635" alt="" class="menu-card__header-image" height="400px" />
  </div>
  <h2 class="menu-card__title">
    Lorem Ipsum
  </h2>
  <p class="menu-card__description">
    Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corrupti, architecto. Repudiandae dolorum incidunt sint ex
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are three reasons your image is not visible when lifted.

- you have `overflow:hidden` on .menu-card
- you have `overflow:hidden` on .menu-card__header
- you have a `clip-path` set on .menu-card__header

You can get the angled effect using a white element positioned at the bottom of the header using a clip-path or css triangle. This would negate the need for the header clip path. Then remove the overflow css and you should get the effect you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you Jason! It worked. I do wonder why using a clip path means that the image stopped being visible?

Comment: Great! Think of a clip path as a boundary with overflow:hidden

Comment: Hmm... That makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would do this differently an instead of `clip-path` I will consider a background on the title section to create the angled shape and yout image will simply be hidden behind. Then you do a simply transform animation and you won't have any issue with overflow.

I replaced the `6vw` with `40px` in the below example:

```css
.menu-card {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: red;
  margin:40px auto;
  width: 80%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  border-radius:0 0 5px 5px;
  max-width: 400px;
}
.menu-card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.menu-card__header {
  background-color: orange;
  max-height: 300px;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.menu-card__header-image {
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.menu-card:hover .menu-card__header-image {
  transform:translateY(-80px);
}
.menu-card__title {
  margin:0;
  padding:15px;
  padding-top:40px; /* space for the triangle shape */
  margin-top:-40px; /* to create the overlap with the top section (same as padding)*/
  background:
    /* top background will take 40px and draw a triangular shape*/
    linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent 49%,#fff 50%)top/100% 40px,
    /* bottom background will take the remaining space as a rectangular shape*/
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) bottom/100% calc(100% - 40px);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  position:relative;
  text-align: center;
}
.menu-card__description {
  margin:0;
  padding: 0 12px 20px;
  background:#fff;
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-card">
  <div class="menu-card__header">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/0/250/635" alt="" class="menu-card__header-image" height="400px" />
  </div>
  <h2 class="menu-card__title">
    Lorem Ipsum
  </h2>
  <p class="menu-card__description">
    Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corrupti, architecto. Repudiandae dolorum incidunt sint ex
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to just change two correction on styles.

1, Remove overflow property from ".menu-card__header"

```
.menu-card__header { /* overflow: hidden; */}
```

2, Add below property on hover

```
&:hover  .menu-card__header {
clip-path: polygon(0 -80px, 100% -80px, 100% calc(100% - 6vw), 0 100%);
```

}

See below jsfiddle example
[here](https://jsfiddle.net/vijaykaneriya/8195uLde/6/)